# Does a question like where can I find good Tutorials for x belong here?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

Do questions like this belong here:

Where can I find a good advanced Tutorial for particles in Nuke?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that such requests be asked directly of the community instead. This leaves it open to either providing our own explication or providing a basic answer with a link to a tutorial that provides more depth. Ex. How do I use particles in nuke to make a title explode?

If the request is too broad it would still be off topic. Ex. How do I make a promotional video?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that still falls under the product recommendation category and thus wouldn't be allowed as its very subjective.